# Select2 multiple tags and formatSelection

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jquery plug in select 2 that generates tags, now I want to make those tags crackable but in result when I set option formatSelection in option as href it gives me something like: Zleceniodawca

Html looks like:

```
<select data-placeholder="Dane z kontraktu" class="select" multiple="multiple" tabindex="6" id="tags">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <optgroup label="System">
                        <?php foreach($config_system as $input => $name) : ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $input; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="Podstawowe">
                        <?php foreach($config_basic as $input => $name) : ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $input; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="Sailing Schedule">
                        <?php foreach($config_ss as $input => $name) : ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $input; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
```

As Jquery code:

```
select: function()
{
    function formatSelection(item) {
        return '<a href="#">' + item.text + '</a>';
    }

    $('#tags').select2({
        formatSelection : formatSelection
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
 $('#tags').select2({
        formatSelection : formatSelection,
        escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try adding the event in both formatResult and formatSelection like I shown below.

```
formatResult: formatSelection,
formatSelection: formatSelection,
```